Are propellers quieter when its drizzling/light rain?
Reading about aircraft noise reduction came across the concept of Micro Jet which apparently injects water into the "tail jet flow field" to reduce noise, so I wonder this concept also translates to open propellers aircraft while in drizzle weather. And if it does, could something like this be installed on open prop aircraft when isn't raining, some sort of mist spray device that can be turned on specially during takeoff and landing(which is the phase where noise reduction is really relevant).

It is my understanding that rain/mist/fog all reduce noise levels in general - is that relevant?

Looking at this paper The Effects of Microjet Injection on an F404 Jet Engine, it seems that there are more parameters than just the presence of water.
They report a noise reduction of max 5dB locally for the following setup:

Pressure (400 psig)
Massflow (in the paper they talk about "8 to 11% of the mass flux of the main jet")
Direction, see the plot below for the influence of the jet angle:


They do not report sensitivities for the variables, but comparing this setup to common drizzle, all factors are very different, so I expect the outcomes to be also very different (likely much less to nothing in the case of drizzle)

This paper sounds like it's discussing a jet engine; the question is about a propeller.

Ah fair point, I saw Microjet and followed the resources leading me to jets.
